# trigger child function from parent component in stencil

Tags: javascript, stenciljs, tsx, stencil-component

How to trigger a child component function from parent component and send data in stenciljs

From `<parent-component>`, I am try run a function onClick and then send the data to `<child-component>` in a function without using @Listen decorator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@Method()` decorator in the child for that:

```
@Component({ tag: 'child-component' })
export class Child {
  @Method()
  async foo() {
    return 'bar';
  }
}
```

```
@Component({ tag: 'parent-component' })
export class Parent {
  @State() childRef?: HTMLChildComponentElement;

  clickHandler = async () => {
    const foo = await this.childRef?.foo();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host onClick={this.clickHandler}>
        <child-component ref={el => (this.childRef = el)} />
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

See https://stenciljs.com/docs/methods.

Also note that the reference is not set until after the child has been rendered (i. e. not yet available in `componentWillLoad`).

---

Since you've mentioned `@Listen`, you might also find it useful that you can pass functions down to children as props (kind of like callbacks).

```
@Component({ tag: 'child-component' })
export class Child {
  @Prop() clickHandler: (e: MouseEvent) => void;

  render() {
    return <Host onClick={this.clickHandler} />;
  }
}
```

```
@Component({ tag: 'parent-component' })
export class Parent {
  render() {
    return <child-component clickHandler={e => console.log(e.target.tagName)} />;
  }
}
```